# Boot2Docker to Google Compute Engine VM: saving Docker container

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I am running Boot2Docker v1.0.1 on Windows, and wish to fire up a Docker container I have created on a Google Compute Engine VM.

In order to do so, I need to save the container and upload it to Google Cloud Storage.
I issue the following command:

docker save --output=mycontainer.tar mycontainer:latest

The command completes without error. However, I cannot find the rce_env.tar file anywhere on my hard drive.

Does anyone have any experience with this? If not, is there a better way to run containers on GCE VM's?

Answer (score 3):

You can run [`google/docker-registry`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/docker-registry/) locally to push your container images to GCS.

```
docker run -ti --name gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk \
  gcloud auth login
docker run -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk \
  gcloud config set project <project>
docker run -d -e GCS_BUCKET=bucketname -p 5000:5000 \
  --volumes-from gcloud-config google/docker-registry
docker tag imagename localhost:5000/imagename
docker push localhost:5000/imagename
```

And then run it on GCE to pull your containers from GCS.

```
docker run -d -e GCS_BUCKET=bucketname -p 5000:5000 google/docker-registry
docker run localhost:5000/imagename
```

Comment: What does google/docker-registry do? (I thought docker's hub used to show you some details about a docker repo, but it doesn't now.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using boot2docker on windows.

On a similar setup, using OSX and [boot2docker 1.1.0](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases/tag/v1.1.0), the following works:

```
docker save --output mycontainer.tar mycontainer:latest
```

As also does redirecting standard output:

```
docker save mycontainer:latest > mycontainer.tar
```

Comment: I see what's happening, the file mycontainer.tar is only accessible within my boot2docker session. When I execute "docker save" and then type "ls" it shows up in the directory within boot2docker. However, it does not seem to be accessible at all on my hard disk. I am currently figuring out if it is possible to push the tar file to Google Cloud Storage from Boot2Docker.

Comment: This seems impossible. I can't install cloud sdk on Boot2Docker because it does not support bash, and I can't docker push a .tar file on the root system to cloud storage. I'm not sure if this would work even if I could. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm really at a loss

Comment: @user3818431 I'm not experienced with boot2docker for windows, but on OSX it installs a `docker` command line tool that can be used from the host. If you don't have the option, you can try configuring VirtualBox shared folders. If that doesn't work either, you can use another docker container with bash support (for instance, using  the `ubuntu` image) and access the file by using docker volumes `docker run -v...`)

Comment: I am sure those are viable solutions, thank you. Right now Boot2Docker for Windows seems to be lacking some vital functionality.

Answer (score 0):

GCE now allows to store docker images for your projects using the gcloud command.

you can now run `$ gcloud preview docker push gcr.io/YOUR-PROJECT/IMAGE-NAME`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/#pushing_to_the_registry